MOSFET Driver Circuit - Current and Waveforms
EXPLANATION
I have a question about the MOSFETs I marked in red in the MOSFET driver circuit whose circuit diagram I gave below.
As you can see, the M6 is P-channel, M4 is N-channel.
When Q17 conducts, M6 is OFF.
When Q18 conducts, M6 ON.
When I check the current flowing through the source of M6 (Is-M6, green trace), I see that it is 0.9 A. You can see it in Picture 2.
0.9 A means that the gate capacitance needs to be charged to open M4 with that current, but the current coming to the gate of M4 (pink trace) is almost 0 A.
Questions

Why is there almost 0 A at the gate of M4, even though 0.9 A is
flowing through M6?
Interestingly, the current is almost 0 A at the gate of M4 when
charging the gate capacitance, but discharging current is almost
3.2 A (pink trace). It is weird to me. What is the reason for this?

Picture 1. Circuit Diagram

Source: me
Picture 2. Waveforms of M6 and M4

Source: me
Picture 3. Waveform of M6 and M5

Source: me
Picture 4. Waveforms of M6, M5 and M4

Source: me
Picture 5. Detailed waveforms of M6,M5 and M4

Source: me

Hello
I would check how much current is flowing in M5. I think the issue is that both M6 and M5 conduct simultaneously a short time which is shoot through.

Thank you for your suggestion, I check the M6 and M5, it seems there is a small shoot through ( Picture 3, recently added ). But the only signal that opens or closes these mosfets are coming from the main AND gate. How can I solve this shoot through ? @Tyassin

Can you show the voltage waveforms for M6 and M5 together with M6 source current and M4 gate current (your first picture), maybe on two different axis?

What do you specifically mean by "open M4"?

Where do you read ''open'' ? I mensioned '' ON'' and '' OFF'' @Andyaka

Hello Sir, I added M6, M5 and M6 measurements. First measurement '' Ig(M4) '' is the gate current of M4. The middle mesurement '' V(d-m5) '' is drain to source voltage measurement of M5. The last measurements '' V(S-M6, D-M6) and Is(M6) '' are the source to drain voltage and current of M6.  I hope that measurment will be usefull for my question @Tyassin

I've quoted you from your question. I have made no mistake.

@Mhan. Sorry I meant the gate voltages of M5 and M6,  not Vds of these.

Another thing. The big difference between the charging current of M4 compared to discharging current is also because you have R15 when charging and just M5 at discharge.

Hello sir, I renewed it in Picture 4 . The middle is the gate voltages. The blue trace is for M5. Pink trace is for M6. The rest is same. @Tyassin

Just another comment. I noticed that M6 has a max Vgs of 12V it could be that you should try the simulation with another type having Vgs_max of 20V if possible to get some more headroom. The model could behave strange when you try to exceed or get very close to the maximum ratings.
In the simulation you can also very easily check to see where the 0.9A are going.

Hello Sir, thank you for your suggestion, I tried another pmos which has 20 V Vgs , the issue still occurs. If you have any other suggestion, I would be very happy @Tyassin

Hello sir, I would be very happy if you can give some advice or suggestion about the question because you are also expert  @G36

Sir, I noticed that when I remove the R15, I can measure the 0.9A at the gate of M4 (green trace ) in the Picture 5. On the other hand some current spikes appeared after the 0.9A. But this time simulation show the source current of M6 as 180A. I think since I removed the R15, Ltspice doens't know how to calculate the current that is why is shows me 180A at M6 but 0.9A at the gate of M4. Another thing to notice is that when gate voltage of M6 is -12 V, the 0.9A of current only appears for a very short time, it should last until the end of -12V but it doesnt in the Picture 5 . @Tyassin

The current into the gate of M4, is expected to be a current pulse. Especially now that R15 is also removed. The 180A is because you now have (as previously mentioned) a shoot-through that are only limited by the Rds-on of M5 and M6.

I am not sure what is going on, but you could also try to split up your design in block and simulate until it behaves as it should.The initial 0.9A of current going through M6 and not entering the gate of M4 should go somewhere, which should be easy to find in your simulation.

I noticed someting. In Picture 5, I put source current of M6 (blue), drain current of M5 (green) and gate current of M4 (pink) on the upper plot. I put gate-source voltage of M6,M5 and M4. I made the colours same for the same mosfets. When blue trace which is gate to source of M6 goes -12 V, the green trace which is the gate to source voltage of M5 is not 0 suddenly , it also takes time, that is why there is shoot-through current. so there is less current for the gate of M4. But there is nothing I can do to avoid this because there is only 1 signal which is coming from AND gate. @Tyassin

Do you have any suggestion about this ? @Tyassin
